# How do I know that the isolation tester is doing its job?

Tags: high-voltage, isolation, test

I am measuring the isolation resistance of a device where the measured value is within the range of just measuring with the test probes hanging freely in open air.
1 kV gives values in gigaohm range.

Any tips on how I can verify that the device has ok resistance, and that I am not just measuring an open circuit due to loose internal wire or not having a proper connection to the tested device?

One quick fix would be to add an internal resistor of known value between HV and GND that has noticeble lower resistance than air, but I have never heard of designing like that, and I feel it would probably cause more problems than it solves

Comment: Welcome! Is this a device you are designing or already purchased? If the latter, does it come with a specification of what isolation it should (at least) have?

Comment: You can use a known resistor (or even a shortcut) at the probes to test that the meter is basically working. That's how one tests every Ohmmeter. Of course, the resistor cannot remain there for the actual test.

Comment: Depending of measuring ... Include a known serial resistance, for example 10 Meg (good quality). When measuring pins are shorted ... you know the value. If isolation is ok, it will not "disturb" measurement (just make a little substration).

Comment: I will have a talk to the HW designer. Its the first time a product has too good isolation for me haha. Usually you can see it clearly when testing your product, that the isolation goes to a known range of lets say 10-15 megaohm, and its a clear solid reference to write in the testing instructions. 
I have not seen these levels on gigaohm before and not sure what to tell the tester in production line...